# Why can I not get the parent of an element from content loaded by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

With this code, the ajax html is loaded fine and the click event triggers but when I try to get the form parent of the clicked button it seems to fail.  The output from the alert is 'undefined'.  How can I get the form data?

```
$( "#offertable" ).load( "offer-get.php", function() {
    //$('#loadingDiv').hide();
    $("#offertable").on('click', '#submit', function(event){
        alert($(this).parents('form:first').attr("action"));
        //event.preventDefault(); // this will prevent from submitting the form

        //$(this).prop('disabled',true);

        var postData = $(this).parents('form:first').serialize();
        var formURL = $(this).parents('form:first').attr("action");
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                alert("Offer updated successfully");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("Failed to update offer");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
} );
```

I've tried using the submit event on the form (which would give me form object that I can get the data from);

```
    $("#offertable").on('submit', '#updateoffer', function(event){
```

But it never fires.

EDIT: Form returned from offer-get.php

```
            <tr>
                <form action="offer-update.php" id="updateoffer" name="updateoffer" method='post'>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pendingofferid" value="<?php echo $record['pendingofferid'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="offerid" value="<?php echo $record['offerid'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="oldpaused" value="<?php echo $record['paused'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="oldpayout" value="<?php echo $record['payout'] ?>">

                    <td><?php echo $record['offerid']; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo $record['picture']; ?>" height="50" width="50"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $record['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $record['trackinglink']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $record['country']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $record['device']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ($approved) : ?>
                            <input type="number" name="payout" min="0" step="0.01" value="<?php echo $record['payout']; ?>">
                        <?php else: echo $record['payout']; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ($approved) : ?>
                            <select name="status"  class="form-control required" >
                                <option value="Live" <?php if(!$paused) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Live</option>
                                <option value="Paused" <?php if($paused) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Paused</option>
                            </select> 
                        <?php else: echo 'Pending'; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ($approved) : ?>
                            <button type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='btn btn-userid'>Update</button>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
```

Obviously this is not the whole code, don't want to release clients sensitive information but this should be enough.  This part is looped for each result from the DB query.  So there are multiple forms with same ids.  If I use different ids for each form, I'm not sure how I'd get the event to fire otherwise since the number of rows isn't known until the data is returned.

Comment: Personally I'd use `.closest("form")` but what you've got *should* work, I think.

Comment: ..... or `this.form` !

Comment: How about posting the HTML ?

Comment: What!? What do you mean by _multiple forms with same ids_?

Comment: You can't re-use "id" values on the same page. Id values must be unique.